# Laravel eager not working with select function

Tags: laravel

If I use select function the data disappears

```
$regions = Region::select('id', 'place_id', 'formatted_address')
        ->where('lang', $lang)
        ->with(['areas' => function($query) {
            return $query
                ->select('id', 'place_id', 'formatted_address') // << the problem is here
                ->whereNotNull('area1')->whereNull('locality')->whereNull('area2');
        }])
        ->get();
```

[image]

if you remove the select function, the areas field is filled with data

Relations:

```
$this->hasMany(Region::class, 'country', 'formatted_address');
```

Comment: Did you try aliasing the inner selected columns?

Comment: if you mean it then yes
 ->select('id as d', 'place_id as place', 'formatted_address as name')

Comment: Can you share the models being used?

Answer (score 0):

The request must contain fields that participate in the relationship

```
$this->hasMany(Region::class, 'country', 'formatted_address');

->select('place_id', 'country', 'formatted_address')
```